# Spark SQL load json throws error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am a newbie to spark and got stuck when tried to run my first Spark SQL code.I ran a simple program to load a json file using spark SQL from eclipse IDE. Here is my code:

```
SparkSession spSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("First SQL code").master("local[2]").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", tempDir).getOrCreate();
spSession.read().csv("data/customerData.json");
Dataset<Row> empDf = spSession.read().json("data/customerData.json");
empDf.show();
empDf.printSchema();
```

Code throws following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class

This is what my pom dependencies looks like:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <!-- Apache Spark main library -->
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems to some issue with the version of spark libraries included in the pom.i did trey it with version 2.3 of and the same was working .Below is the code and pom which i have used

```
SparkSession spSession = SparkSession.builder()
                                     .appName("First SQL code")
                                     .master("local[*]")
                                     .getOrCreate();


Dataset<String> empDf = spSession.read()
                                 .format("json")
                                 .textFile("C:\\Users\\Kiran\\workspace\\JsonSpark\\input\\");


empDf.show();
empDf.printSchema();
```

**dependency**

```
 <dependency>
    <!-- Apache Spark main library -->
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, changing the version of spark to 2.3.0 worked for me also.. But could you tell how can I make it work with spark version 2.0.0 because 2.0.0 is the version that I intend to use for my project